# Reading file to string (python)

Tags: python, string, file

I just installed Anaconda to a Windows 10 machine (Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)|)
I am having an issue reading text from a file.
Please see code and output below.  I want the actual text from the file.

Thanks!!

Output:

```
 ['\xff\xfeT\x00h\x00i\x00s\x00',
  '\x00i\x00s\x00',
   '\x00a\x00',
   '\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00.\x00',
   '\x00',
   '\x00',
   '\x00',
   '\x00T\x00h\x00i\x00s\x00',
   '\x00i\x00s\x00',
   '\x00a\x00',
   '\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00']
```

Code:

```
try:    
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:        
        text = f.read()
except Exception as e:
    print e
    print text.split()
```

test.txt:

```
This is a test.

This is a test
```

Comment: Thanks. The text in the file was using encoding = "Unicode".  Changed to "Ansi", and it works fine now.

Comment: If you've gotten an answer that best meets your needs, feel free to mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the best luck with using the `io` module to open the file with an explicit encoding.

```
import io
with io.open(FILE, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    job = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the text encoding. You file is not encoded in UTF-8, but in UTF-16. Instead of using open, use:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Or switch to Python3 that has a much better support for unicode.